# Can Pandas run on Google App Engine for Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pandas

Can the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) data analysis module run on Google App Engine?

My first inclination is no: the web page states "critical code paths **compiled to C**". So since this is not a purely python package, you cannot simply copy a directory or ZIP file into your app engine project.

Is it possible to "disable" the C extensions and have the module run in pure python (albeit slower)?

Comment: I don't think so, pandas **heavily** uses C (so you can't just disable it), although interestingly [numpy can be used by GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27)...

Comment: I think those third-party libraries are specifically set up by Google to work with app engine. Perhaps pandas would require the same treatment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of today, Google App Engine Python 2.7 runtime [doesn't currently allow](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Pure_Python) running arbitrary C extensions.

But it does allow [inclusion](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Configuring_Libraries) of [third party library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27) that have been hand selected by the engineering team based on their popularity and developer demand.

You can request for a specific library to be included by filling a feature request on the [**public issue tracker**](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8620). If it gets enough ☆☆☆ it is likely to be considered for inclusion in an upcoming release.

Comment: I created [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8620) and added the link in your answer.

Comment: Great. Visitors to this question: please click through and star the issue if you would like to see pandas added to GAE.

Comment: Well done Andy Hayden, proppy and CrossProduct for the public issue. I just voted for it and got a response from a project-member: "... With the new Managed VMs it's possible to run any libraries you like on app engine backends, including pandas ..." ; It's not yet a GAE  solution, but you definitely got their attention!

Comment: it's been two years, fml

Comment: As of recently, App Engine now supports arbitrary C libraries via the flexible framework environment.