# Trying to use pandas and xlsx writer in GAE

Tags: python, excel, google-app-engine, pandas

So I have created a basic local page on GAE which has a header, a field, and a submit button. My end goal is to create a local page which will take an input of a dataframe from pandas in the field, and convert that to an excel file when I hit the submit button. I have a program written in python already to do this, but I can't figure out how to transfer that over. Here is my code for the page I have already:
import webapp2

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        myPage = """
          <html>
            <body>
              <form action="/hello" method="get">
                <div>

                    <input type="text" name="yourname" size="30" maxlength="30"></input>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit dataframe">
                </div>
              </form>
            </body>
          </html>
          """
        self.response.out.write(myPage)

class hello(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        yourname = self.request.get('yourname')      
        self.response.out.write(yourname + " to you too")

    application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage),('/hello', hello)], debug=True)
```

When I try to `import xlsxwriter` or `pandas` my page won't load. I tried to update my yaml file, but to no avail. I really need to figure out how to do this. It seems like it should be fairly easy, but I don't know where to go from here. In my mind I should be able to just:

```
import xlsxwriter, pandas, os, re
```

copy and paste in my other code which only uses those things
make the call: `custom_tabs(yourname)`, which will take in the dataframe and spit out the excel doc.

Comment: No can't do that, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144867/can-pandas-run-on-google-app-engine-for-python