# PyDev and Eclipse - ImportError No Module Named - after refreshing interpreter

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, pydev, wsgi, importerror

I'm new to Eclipse and PyDev and have been stuck on this for while having had a look at quite a few answers to similar issues on here.

I'm trying to build a simple web app using PyDev, Eclipse, Python 2.7 and Flask (on Windows) and have followed this guide (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/getting-started/python-standard-env) which all worked fine.

I made some small changes, but am currently stuck on the first step where I am trying to import pandas in my script (main.py)

I'm getting this error from the debugger when I try to import pandas from in my script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler

    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject

    obj = __import__(path[0])

  File "C:\Users\LONTI\workspace\Flask-app\main.py", line 3, in <module>

    import pandas as pd

ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I've checked in **Preferences > Interpreters > Python Interpreter** that **C:\Python27\lib\site-packages** has been added (where my pandas module sits). I've also tried removing and adding the interpreter again but to no avail.

Also, in the editor I can see that pandas isn't Unresolved, so it seems like it can 'see' it. And in the workspace, under the Python > System Libs > lib/site-packages that pandas is also there.

I'm a bit at a loss where else to check.

main.py looks like this, where I've just cut out as much as possible to try and make sure there wasn't anything else that affect the import:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/form')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/submitted', methods=['POST'])
def submitted_form():

    name = request.form['name']
    pc1 = request.form['pc1']
    pc2 = request.form['pc2']
    pc3 = request.form['pc3']

    return render_template(
    'submitted_form.html',
    name=name,
    pc1=pc1,
    pc2=pc2,
    pc3=pc3)

@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    # Log the error and stacktrace.
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return 'An internal error occurred.', 500
```

Thanks in advance for your help and let me know if I need to provide any more info .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're using google-app-engine, which limits what's allowed to run.

[Can Pandas run on Google App Engine for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144867/can-pandas-run-on-google-app-engine-for-python) has information which may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The import error in particular is caused by improper installation of `pandas` in your application. See  [Using third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27). From [Installing a third-party library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#installing_a_third-party_library):

> In order to use a third-party library, copy it into a folder in your
>   project's source directory. The library must be implemented as pure
>   Python code with no C extensions. The code is uploaded to App Engine
>   with your application code, and counts towards file quotas.

This quote also ties into the answer mentioned by Fabio, it's unlikely you'll get this working on the standard GAE environment.

It *might* work on the [flex environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/) - less restrictions, but that's a significantly different beast.